# How to save the data of recyclerview LiveData<List<SportData>> to avoid the loss of bottom navigation data?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

The data in the recyclerview in my fragment uses the api of the website. But the data is lost when the bottom navigation is switched. But the data structure is not a simple int or string. How should I write it in onSaveInstanceState to store it. And how to make him restore the data type of LiveData<List> normally?

The data of the recyclerview looks like in the viewmodel.

```
private val _photos = MutableLiveData<List<SportData>>()
    val photos: LiveData<List<SportData>> get() = _photos
```

data class

```
@Parcelize
data class SportData (
    val GymID:Int,
    val Photo1:String,
    val Name:String,
    val Address:String,
    val OperationTel:String,
    val OpenState:String, 
    val GymFuncList:String 
): Parcelable
```

I try to save the data in onDestroyView() and fetch it in onViewCreated. It fails with null.

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
        photos2=viewModel.photos
        super.onDestroyView()
        Log.d("aaa","destroyVIEW and ${photos2}")
    }
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
   
        Log.d("aaa","=viewCreate and ${photos2}")
        if (photos2!=null){
            viewModel.saveData(photos2!!)
        }
```

viewmodel

```
fun saveData(savePhoto:LiveData<List<SportData>>){
        _photos=savePhoto as MutableLiveData<List<SportData>>
    }
```

hello can you help me? thanks

Comment: Have you consider saving your objects in database once they are downloaded and use it to present the data to ui layer?

Comment: Currently not saving data with room.

Comment: Do you understand what `onSaveInstanceState` is supposed to do? I can't think of any reason why you would need to use it to back up data that's in the ViewModel. The ViewModel will outlive the Fragment during a configuration change, so saving instance state is pointless.

Comment: I thought I lost the fragment recyclerview data because of the bottom navigation switch. I can use it to save it. So how should I make the fragment still the screen I just saw after switching the bottom navigation?

Comment: Are you using the Navigation Component? Are you using Navigation 2.4 (currently 2.4.0-rc01)? Only Navigation 2.4 saves and restores the state of each bottom nav item.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation

Comment: I checked the dependencies. Currently using 2.3.5 which matches the website description

Comment: use androidx.navigation:navigation-*:2.4.0-rc01....After the bottom navigation is switched, the original recycleriview data will still be blank.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is already at ViewModel. You don't need to save it. Since data in your viewModel and viewModel lives while your aplication lives, you'll not lose it.

What might be happening is a reload when you go back to your list's fragment, right?

You are calling a viewModel method from your fragment. This method does the request.

What you need to do is to make sure your fragment won't call it if it doesn't need.

What you need to do is:

```
if (savedBundleState == null) { //Read this as android creating this frag for the very first time
     //Here you call viewmodel method that does the request.
}
```

This is part 1

Since you are using Navigation Component, you'll need to setup it to avoid new fragments killing older fragments.

Comment: override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (savedInstanceState==null){
            viewModel._photos=viewModel._photos
        }
        
    }. But when the fragment navigates back at the bottom, it still displays a white screen. It does not match the original picture.